# Eucalyptus Cloud not booting

Tags: centos, cloud, eucalyptus

I have installed Eucalyptus Cloud in a Box (Bundled with CentOS 6.4 64 bit)on an **HP Probook 430 G1** laptop with the following processor specifications

**Intel i7 4500u**

Before Install I get the message **"Unsupported Hardware of combination thereof detected"**.
Inspite of this I can still install Eucalyptus just fine.

However, after the first reboot and subsequent reboots I see a message

**Detected CPU model 6 family 69**

**UNSUPPORTED HARDWARE device: Intel CPU Model**

After this the machine does not go beyond the first loading screen.

```
1).Is this a problem with the new fourth generation Haswell architecture ?

2).And is there any solution to this apart from using another machine ? 

3).What does CPU model 6 family 69 mean ?

4).Is there any way to know which specific hardware is unsupported ?
```

Below is the link that shows the supported hardware of Red Hat 
https://hardware.redhat.com/laptop/Hewlett%20Packard/&quicksearch=

Thank you in advance. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, I believe "Model 6 Family 69" is a 4th generation Haswell i7.
2. You should be able to add "unsupported_hardware" to your kickstart file, if that's when it's occurring.
3. I don't know, but here's Intel's information page for what I think is a typical 4th gen processor:  http://ark.intel.com/products/76087/Intel-Core-i7-4750HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz
4. You could look at the kernel source for the kernel you're using.  Might be in arch/x86/kernel/cpu somewhere.

The "Feature" explained

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Features/WarnTaintedHardware

This says it should only affect the installer, so the "subsequent reboots" behavior you describe should not happen unless you're running the installer on every boot.

And a recent feature added to kickstart to allow it to boot unattended:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/6.4_Technical_Notes/

BZ#824963
A kickstart installation on unsupported hardware resulted in a dialog box asking for confirmation before proceeding with the installation process. As a consequence, it was not possible to perform a kickstart installation on unsupported hardware without any user input. To fix this bug, a new unsupported_hardware kickstart command has been added, which skips the interactive dialog warning when installing a system on unsupported hardware without user input.